# Fetching data and compering in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

Can any one help me .How can a fetch the remote data using WEB API's or SERVER API's with of JSON & then store into SQLite  table in  iphone how can do this .For fetching data I want to use JSON.In SQLite database table is user_detailes  which has username & password .And the server also has the same data which i want  fetch. 
Help me to this.

Give some hints or links or sample to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSString * txtUsername = @"";

```
NSString * txtPassword = @"";

sqlite3 *database;

NSString *sqlStatement = @"";

if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
{

    sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithString:@"select * from account_info "];
    NSLog(@"%@",sqlStatement);
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlStatement cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {

        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
        {
            txtUsername = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)] retain];
            txtPassword = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)] retain];

        }
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    sqlite3_close(database);
```

if(txtUsername isEqulaToString:@"user1"])
{
  //use UIAlertView here
}

Comment: I am not getting you Where should i add this .I have two UITextfield user and password and on button click. Whether it add to the login action or into delegate file.

Comment: ok if i m right then you want to check for username entered by user in text field to the username stored in database and show a confermation if both mathced

Comment: then in above code i m getting txtUsername which is username stored in database what you need to do is to compare this with your text field value by using [txtUsername isEqualToString:[textField text]];

Comment: sqlite3_finalize(statment);
          sqlite3_close(database);
  if([txtUsername isEqulaToString:[NSString *user = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"%@",txtuser]nil]&& [txtPassword isEqulaToString:[NSString *user = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"%@",txtpass]nil]])
   { 
    UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"You are  vaild user" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
   }
   
I am doing like that it show me error ':' before '*' token

Comment: i found that you are missing * in UIAlertView alert